# Does the kovri pre-alpha build already work for running a monero node?

Tags: monerod, privacy, kovri, i2p, tor

As i understand [`kovri`](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri) aims to add support for the [I2P](https://geti2p.net/) network through C++ code instead of the java code it is originally built on. Not only as a monero specific implementation, but also as a general [I2P](https://geti2p.net/) router, usable by other projects as well.

If i currently go to the trouble of building it, can a monero node be run on it on the mainnet/stablenet (as in non-testnet)? If so, does that even make sense at the moment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Kovri FAQ](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri-docs/blob/master/i18n/en/faq.md#what-is-the-current-state-of-kovri):

> #### What is the current state of Kovri?
>
> Kovri is in active development and currently pre-alpha. Kovri is not yet integrated with monero but, in addition to several core features, we are developing a [client](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/issues/351) and [core](https://github.com/monero-project/kovri/issues/350) API for monero and other applications to use.
>
> Currently, you can use the Kovri to connect to (and partake in) the I2P network: browse eepsites, connect to IRC, and run client and server tunnels.
>
> ---
>
> #### Is Kovri usable, partially usable, or recommended to not be used for actual privacy at the moment?
>
> Kovri is usable to the extent of what `./kovri --help` has to offer. Kovri currently has no interaction with Monero. With regard to privacy, we have fixed many security issues since inception but we are still in pre-alpha.
>
> There is still much code to cover so don't expect a strong guarantee of anonymity like with Tor or even java I2P. Those projects have 10+ years of research and implementation experience - and we are just getting started.
>
> Feel free to play the role of developer and experiment/play with Kovri but only if not being anonymous doesn't put you in danger - as there is always the risk of possible de-anonymization due to being in pre-alpha (this is not unique to Kovri).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Pretty dull of me, overlooking the doc/ folder at github, which includes the FAQ.